# Kubernetes Host IP For Vault Authentication with Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-apiserver

I was trying to Authenticate Kubernetes with External Vault using Hashicorps tutorial, https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/identity-access-management/vault-agent-k8s

In below configuration, we have to provide the `END POINT` to our cluster in `K8S_HOST`

```
vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
        token_reviewer_jwt="$SA_JWT_TOKEN" \
        kubernetes_host="https://$K8S_HOST:8443" \
        kubernetes_ca_cert="$SA_CA_CRT"
```

I have setup the Kubernetes HA Cluster in private subnet and an ALB in frontend. I need help in configuring `K8S_HOST` end point.

As of now i have generated `SSL Certs` and recreated dashboard. 
Tried exposing the `kubernetes-dashboard` as `node port`.
Updated the certificate in ALB which is listening on 443. 
But still it not connecting to cluster.

So my doubt is  `K8S_HOST:8443` is the same end point for kubernetes dashboard or something else?

Proper way to get `K8S_HOST` details from a cluster in private subnet.

Can someone please help on this? I am struck here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `kubectl config view` command to view cluster configuration:

```sh
$ kubectl config view --flatten --minify
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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

    server: https://127.0.0.1:32769 # <<-----------here
  name: kind-kind
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kind-kind
    user: kind-kind
  name: kind-kind
current-context: kind-kind
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kind-kind
... ... ...
```

Copy the `server` address and use it as `kubernetes_host` while configuring Vault kubernetes auth method.

```
$ vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
           token_reviewer_jwt="eyJhbGciOiJSUz....." \
           kubernetes_host="https://127.0.0.1:32769" \
           kubernetes_ca_cert=@examples/guides/vault-server/ca.crt
```

**N.B.:** If the `server` address does not contain a port number, no need to add them. Keep the address as it is.

Demo sever address for GKE:

```yaml
server: https://35.203.181.169
```

Demo server address for DigitalOcean k8s cluster:

```yaml
server: https://e8dabcb3-**bb-451e****d5.k8s.ondigitalocean.com
```

Comment: So I have one doubt, the ip which is showing in my cluster config is its private. In vault documentation it mentioned that vault will communicate to Kubernetes through this endpoint. In such case how the vault in another network will get communicated?

Comment: Also in my case, I have HA cluster with three master nodes. So the `kube config view` in each node will return 3 different private ip address. Hence i have to do this via ALB and listener.

Comment: Have you tried using the loadbalancer IP? Since loadbalancer fronts all api-servers (master nodes), or DNS entry which maps to those nodes. Theoretically, it should work.

Comment: added target group and listener and registered instances to listen on port `6443`. As the api server is listening over https. I have added the same certificate `/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.crt and key` to alb. But when I tried loading url in browser I got popup of  insecure SSL , but did got any response for the apiserver.

Comment: Iam thinking like, once I got some response from that, I can try with vault

Comment: Can you run the following command and add the response to the question body? `curl --cacert ${CACERT} --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -X GET ${APISERVER}/api` . Use your LA ip and port in the place of APISERVER.

Comment: `curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name 'kubernetes' does not match target host name 'XXXX.elb.amazonaws.com'`

Comment: @JithZ, can you change the port to `443`, try again?

Comment: Which port?, Alb is already listening on 443 and and forwarding to 6443, the port which kube config view is returning.

Comment: See, still I have doubt on whether the correct certificates I have imported or not. I have also tried with all certificate available. Really confused here.

Comment: As you said, your ALB is listening to 443 then why are you using `https://$K8S_HOST:8443` instead of `https://$K8S_HOST:443`?

Comment: Oh sorry that's the default configuration I have copied in my question, previously I have tried with that now I have changed.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved.
I have to add the alb dns name to api server certificate and then reboot all node.
Authentication is now working fine.